# LMS Moodle install on 20.04 LTS server

Tags: snap, webserver, moodle

I am not able to install the learning management system Moodle on Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Nextcloud has been installed using snap command and working well

Now I am unable to install Moodle on the same hardware.

Any suggestions

Comment: What happens if you try to install it? It is a matter of downloading the zip, uploading the files to the server and browsing the topmost `index.php` file.

Comment: Have you tried the step-by-step guide from the official Moodle site? Their documentation is actually quite detailed and you should be able to get at least a local instance of moodle running.
https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu